# How Can Add ArrayList into a SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I have array list of integer that i want to add in one column of `sqlite` 
database,

I do this by `contentValues` like this:

> contentValues.put(Tag.REPORT_LATITUDE_LIST, report.getLatitudes());

first! what is the `type` of this `column` in database `table`?

and

how can I get these `arrayList` data from `sqlite`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could serialize your object to JSON, store it in this format as a string and just deserialize it when you read it.

```
 contentValues.put(Tag.REPORT_LATITUDE_LIST, new Gson().toJson(report.getLatitudes()));
```

You would need to add Gson to your gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

}

Comment: It'll be stored as a string